# What does one suppose $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}$ an integer is to solve which of $x,y$, $\sqrt{x}$, $x\cdot y$ are integers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, integers

If the square of $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}$ is an integer, which of the following must be a perfect square, if $x$ and $y$ are positive integers?

Choose all that apply.

A:$x$

B:$y$

C:$\sqrt{x}$

D:$x+y$

E: $x y$

The square of $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}$ is $x+2\sqrt{xy}+y.$

Suppose the square of $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}$ is two.

Then, May you suppose $x+y=2$ and $2 \sqrt{xy}=1$ and solve for x and y via -quadratic formula?

Then suppose the square of $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}$ is three, and eventually work out x,y with assumptions.

Will that solve the problem?

What's the best numbers to suppose the square of  $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}$ is?

Comment: Hint: the square root of a nonnegative integer is either an integer or irrational.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With it given that $x,y \in Z^{+}$, suppose for $k \in Z$, that $(\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y})^2 = k$ and then $x + y + 2\sqrt{xy} = k$ which means $k - x - y = 2\sqrt{xy}$. Since the left hand side of the equation $\in Z$, it follows that $2\sqrt{xy}$ must also be $\in Z$, but since $x,y$ are positive integers, $\sqrt{xy}$ is either a positive integer or irrational. If it were irrational, then $2\sqrt{xy} \notin Q$ and hence $2\sqrt{xy} \notin Z$, so we must have that $\sqrt{xy} \in Z^{+}$.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is $E)$. From what you got, $xy$ must be a perfect square for $\sqrt{xy}$ to be an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Substituting in $x=y=3$ immediately rules out options A, B, C and D. E is the only correct option. To show that, we first square $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}$ which gives $x+2\sqrt{xy}+y$. As this expression is an integer and $x$ and $y$ are both integers, $\sqrt{xy}$ is an integer, implying that $xy$ is a perfect square.

Thus, substituting in $x=y=3$ appears to be the best option, ruling out four option at a time.